# Defining a component to have a name prefix different than its ClassName (minus the "T")

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, when the IDE inserts a new component at design time, it gives its name a prefix which is the ClassName minus the leading "T" and then adds a number that makes its name unique.

This [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62935478/5873732) asks how to change the prefix part of the component's name, so that

```
Edit1
```

could be changed to

```
ed1
```

The accepted answer refers to the "rename components" utility in GExperts, which is fine so far as it goes.

However, is there a way I can always get the same, non-standard, prefix for a component without having to create and install a descendant component in the Componxent Palette?  I know how to do this but it is an unwelcome chore if I want to do it for more than one component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that Q&A, too.

It seemed to me to be a special case of something [I wrote an answer for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61343387), how to specify
defaults for the properties of components added to a form.  It is rather long-winded
and doesn't work for the component's Name property.  However, it can be made to work
for the Name, too, with some quite minor modifications, so that it will now support a specfication
of defaults like this:

```
[TMemo]
Lines.Strings=

[TEdit]
Font.Name=Courier New
Font.Size=11

[TButton]
Name=btn
Caption=

[TCheckBox]
Name=cb
Caption=
```

Note that the TButton and TCheckBox use non-standard Name prefixes and a blank Caption.
The blank Caption is to save having to rub out the default the IDE provides.

The full code of the unit which needs to be added to a design-time package and installed in the IDE is below.  The main change,
compared to my previous answer, is that the component's Name property is handled separately from
any other properties by this

```
procedure TDesignNotifierForm.SetComponentName(AComponent : TComponent; AComponentName : String);
var
  AOwner : TComponent;
begin
  //    First, try to find the component's Form.  We need this so that we can ask the Form's
  //    Designer to generate a unique name for the component instance (Comp1, Comp2, etc).
  AOwner := AComponent.Owner;
  while (AOwner <> Nil) and not(AOwner is TForm) do
    AOwner := AOwner.Owner;

  if AOwner is TForm then begin
    AComponentName := TForm(AOwner).Designer.UniqueName(AComponentName);
    AComponent.Name := AComponentName;
    TForm(AOwner).Designer.Modified;  //  Notify the Form's Designer
  end;
end;

procedure TDesignNotifierForm.SetComponentProperties(AComponent : TComponent; ComponentClassName : String);
var
  i : Integer;
  AString : String;
  Index : Integer;
begin

  //    Note:  The defaults which can be set include the Component's Name.  For simplicity, it can be included
  //    amongst the other defaults but requires special treatment (see SetComponentName).
  //
  if Ini.SectionExists(ComponentClassName) then begin
    Ini.ReadSectionValues(ComponentClassName, SL);
    Index := SL.IndexOfName('Name');
    if Index >= 0  then begin
      AString := SL.Values['Name'];
      SetComponentName(AComponent, AString);
    end;

    for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do begin
      if i <> Index then begin
        AString := ComponentClassName + '.' + SL[i];
        SetComponentProperty(AComponent, AString);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Unit code:

```
unit DesignNotifierFormu;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, TypInfo, ToolsApi, DesignIntf, IniFiles;

const
  WM_CompInserted = WM_User + 1;

type
  TDesignNotifierForm = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure SetComponentProperties(AComponent : TComponent; ComponentClassName: String);
    procedure SetComponentName(AComponent: TComponent; AComponentName: String);
  public
    AComp : TComponent;
    Ini : TMemIniFile;
    SL : TStringList;
    procedure Log(const Title, Msg : String);
    procedure WMCompInserted(var Msg : TMsg); message WM_CompInserted;
  end;

  TDesignNotification = class(TInterfacedObject, IDesignNotification)
    F : TDesignNotifierForm;
    procedure ItemDeleted(const ADesigner: IDesigner; AItem: TPersistent);
    procedure ItemInserted(const ADesigner: IDesigner; AItem: TPersistent);
    procedure ItemsModified(const ADesigner: IDesigner);
    procedure SelectionChanged(const ADesigner: IDesigner;
      const ASelection: IDesignerSelections);
    procedure DesignerOpened(const ADesigner: IDesigner; AResurrecting: Boolean);
    procedure DesignerClosed(const ADesigner: IDesigner; AGoingDormant: Boolean);
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  DesignNotification : TDesignNotification;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TDesignNotification.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  F := TDesignNotifierForm.Create(Nil);
  F.Show;
  F.Log('Event', 'Notifier created');
end;

procedure TDesignNotification.DesignerClosed(const ADesigner: IDesigner;
  AGoingDormant: Boolean);
begin
end;

procedure TDesignNotification.DesignerOpened(const ADesigner: IDesigner;
  AResurrecting: Boolean);
var
  C : TComponent;
  Msg : String;
begin
  EXIT;  //  following for experimenting only
  C := ADesigner.Root;
  if C <> Nil then begin
    Msg := C.ClassName;
    //  At this point, you can call ShowMessage or whatever you like
    ShowMessage(Msg);
  end
  else
    Msg := 'no root';
  F.Log('Designer Opened', Msg);
end;

destructor TDesignNotification.Destroy;
begin
  F.Close;
  F.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TDesignNotification.ItemDeleted(const ADesigner: IDesigner;
  AItem: TPersistent);
begin
end;

procedure TDesignNotification.ItemInserted(const ADesigner: IDesigner;
  AItem: TPersistent);
var
  S : String;
begin
  if AItem is TComponent then begin
    S := 'Component name: ' + TComponent(AItem).Name;
    F.AComp := TComponent(AItem);
    PostMessage(F.Handle, WM_CompInserted, 0, 0);
  end
  else
    S := 'Item';
  F.Log('Designer', ADesigner.GetComponentName(TComponent(AItem)));
  F.Log('ItemInserted', S);
end;

procedure TDesignNotification.ItemsModified(const ADesigner: IDesigner);
begin
end;

procedure TDesignNotification.SelectionChanged(const ADesigner: IDesigner;
  const ASelection: IDesignerSelections);
begin
end;

procedure SetUp;
begin
  DesignNotification := TDesignNotification.Create;
  RegisterDesignNotification(DesignNotification);
end;

procedure TDesignNotifierForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Ini := TMemIniFile.Create('d:\aaad7\ota\componentdefaults\defaults.ini');
  SL := TStringList.Create;
end;

procedure TDesignNotifierForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SL.Free;
  Ini.Free;
end;

procedure SplitStr(const Input, Delim : String; var Head, Tail : String);
var
  P : Integer;
begin
  P := Pos(Delim, Input);
  if P = 0 then begin
    Head := Input;
    Tail := '';
  end
  else begin
    Head := Copy(Input, 1, P - 1);
    Tail := Copy(Input, P + Length(Delim), MaxInt);
  end;
end;

procedure SetComponentProperty(AComponent : TComponent; AString : String);
var
  Value,
  Head,
  Tail,
  ObjName,
  PropName : String;
  Obj : TObject;
  AType : TTypeKind;
begin
  //  needs to Use TypInfo
  SplitStr(AString, '=', PropName, Value);
  if PropName = '' then else;

  SplitStr(PropName, '.', Head, Tail);

  if Pos('.', Tail) = 0 then begin
    SetStrProp(AComponent, Tail, Value);
  end
  else begin
    SplitStr(Tail, '.', ObjName, PropName);
    Obj := GetObjectProp(AComponent, ObjName);
    if Obj is TStrings then begin
      //  Work around problem setting e.g. TMemo.Lines.Text
      TStrings(Obj).Text := Value;
    end
    else begin
      AType := PropType(Obj, PropName);
      case AType of
        //  WARNING - incomplete list
        tkString,
        tkLString : SetStrProp(Obj, PropName, Value);
        tkInteger : SetOrdProp(Obj, PropName, StrToInt(Value));
        tkFloat : SetFloatProp(Obj, PropName, StrToFloat(Value));
      end; { case }
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure TDesignNotifierForm.SetComponentName(AComponent : TComponent; AComponentName : String);
var
  AOwner : TComponent;
begin
  //    First, try to find the component's Form.  We need this so that we can ask the Form's
  //    Designer to generate a unique name for the component instance (Comp1, Comp2, etc).
  AOwner := AComponent.Owner;
  while (AOwner <> Nil) and not(AOwner is TForm) do
    AOwner := AOwner.Owner;

  if AOwner is TForm then begin
    AComponentName := TForm(AOwner).Designer.UniqueName(AComponentName);
    AComponent.Name := AComponentName;
    TForm(AOwner).Designer.Modified;  //  Notify the Form's Designer
  end;
end;

procedure TDesignNotifierForm.SetComponentProperties(AComponent : TComponent; ComponentClassName : String);
var
  i : Integer;
  AString : String;
  Index : Integer;
begin

  //    Note:  The defaults which can be set include the Component's Name.  For simplicity, it can be included
  //    amongst the other defaults but requires special treatment (see SetComponentName).
  //
  if Ini.SectionExists(ComponentClassName) then begin
    Ini.ReadSectionValues(ComponentClassName, SL);
    Index := SL.IndexOfName('Name');
    if Index >= 0  then begin
      AString := SL.Values['Name'];
      SetComponentName(AComponent, AString);
    end;

    for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do begin
      if i <> Index then begin
        AString := ComponentClassName + '.' + SL[i];
        SetComponentProperty(AComponent, AString);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TDesignNotifierForm.WMCompInserted(var Msg: TMsg);
var
  S : String;
begin
  if AComp <> Nil then
    S := AComp.Name
  else
    S := 'Name not known';
  Log('WMCompInserted', S);

  SetComponentProperties(AComp, AComp.ClassName);

  AComp := Nil; // We're done with AComp
end;

procedure TDesignNotifierForm.Log(const Title, Msg: String);
begin
  if csDestroying in ComponentState then
    exit;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Title + ': ' + Msg);
end;

initialization
  SetUp;
finalization
  if DesignNotification <> Nil then begin
    UnRegisterDesignNotification(DesignNotification);
  end;
end.
```